# Mesh appears transparent in Unity, even after flipping normals

Tags: transparency, normals, unity

Mesh appears transparent in Unity, even after flipping normals. Also tried recalculating the normals inside and outside and didn't work.

How it appears in Blender:
[image]

How it appears in Unity:
[image]

Comment: There's an option to show normals in Blender to check if they're correct. Are you sure it's not a reflective material?

Comment: I've already resolved this issue that way. The normals were flipped. Thanks.